# How to remove hash parameters from URL in GWT application

Tags: java, url, gwt

For example i have below url:

```
http://server:port/?parameter#token;ID=com.test;args=one&two&three
```

Here if i want to remove ID and args from the URL without reloading the page then how to do it.

Note:Right now i am doing it with below code and i am looking for the better option

```
 PlaceRequest currentPlaceRequest = placeManager.getCurrentPlaceRequest();
        final String counts= currentPlaceRequest.getParameter( "args", null );
        String id = currentPlaceRequest.getParameter( "ID", null );
        String url = Window.Location.getHref();
        if( counts!= null && !counts.isEmpty() )
        {

            if( id!= null && !id.isEmpty() )
            {

                String counts= ";" + "args" + "=" + counts;
                String urlToReplace = url.replace( counts, "" );       
                Window.Location.replace( urlToReplace );
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the current token using [`History.getToken`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/History.html#getToken()), process it and then set it using [`History.newItem`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/History.html#newItem(java.lang.String)). Note that depending on your setup (using [Activities and Places](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces.html) or mvp4g/gwtp, etc) this could trigger another activity in your application.